# Where is the test apk located in Android Project?

Tags: android, android-testing

For running tests, Android Studio/Gradle generates a test apk which performs tests on the app apk. Can anyone share where the test apk gets generated and the location inside the project?

Following is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.ark.beacons_test"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 25
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }

   packagingOptions {
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
   }

}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar,*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
   compile(name: 'android-lib', ext: 'aar')
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
   compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2' 
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The test apk is generated in rootProject/app/build/outputs/apk/ folder. But to generate the test.apk file, you have to add instrumented tests in src/androidTest folder, atleast one dummy test. Then run the tests on a device by right clicking in project explorer and then select "Run All Tests" or "Run Tests"  -->

[image]

Once you run the tests, then and then only a test.apk file gets created in the above mentioned folder.

Comment: Wonderful this is the key answer. Thanks alot @ARK.

Answer (score 5):

For Kotlin projects it might be at:
`<yourproject>/app/build/intermediates/apk/androidTest/debug`

Answer (score 4):

Do not confuse app apk and test apk. 
In my case, app apk is called app-debug.apk and is located in
`\app\build\outputs\apk\debug`
and test apk is called app-debug-androidTest.apk and is located in
`\app\build\outputs\apk\androidTest\debug`. 
Both of them you load simultaneously in Firebase Test Lab.

Answer (score 1):

/YourProject/app/build/outputs/apk

Comment: Don't see it. Do I need additional code to see the testApk. I have /androidTest and /test dir in src/ and also declared AndroidTestRunner in app/build.gradle

Comment: YourProject means the root dir of your project where the gradle folder and the build.gradle file is located

Comment: I got that. Don't see the test.apk in /YourProject/app/build/outputs/apk

Comment: If you still don't find at the mentioned location, try building the apk in the android studio first.

Comment: Open up your android studio, Build->Build APK. Android studio would even prompt where the apk is located

Comment: still no luck in getting the test apk. Build SDK generated only debug and release apks. Didn't see the test.apk :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142866/discussion-between-akshayraj-kore-and-arunava).

Comment: @ARK could you please share with us what the root-cause of the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Android - ProjectRootDirectory/bin/debug/PackageName.apk

Android - /AppRootFolder/app/build/outputs/apk/YourApksHere

Comment: don't see the projectroot/bin/ dir in Android project

Comment: Are you sure you have built the project. One way to ensure that you get an apk output in the above folders is to press the debug on device option. The apk will be generated and placed on the emulator. It will also be placed in the apk folder as well

Answer (score -1):

C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk

Comment: app\build\outputs\apk      - this is common